# VueJS и Google robot - We're sorry but <domain> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue

Tags: vue.js, robots.txt

Как подружить приложение VueJs с роботом Google

Comment: Насколько знаю, подружить их могут только великие и ужасные сысыг и сысыр (SSG и SSR). То есть, для этого можно/нужно использовать Nuxt.

Comment: нету ноды на проде и переписывать бэк не вариант

Comment: Тогда тебе придется переписывать гугл, т.к. ему эти частные проблемы совершенно безразличны. Хоть его пауки и могут понимать генерируемый js-скриптами контент, индексируется такой контент не всегда успешно - тогда как генерация статики дает 100% результат.

Comment: VPS с виртуализацией KVM (чтобы докер юзать) у немцев кстати стоит 4€/мес - это не такие уж великие деньги за генерилку статики. С облачным решением на повременной оплате, будет еще дешевле. Прописать обращение к генерилке по принципу реверспрокси, чтобы без редиректов (пришел паучок - фетчим и отдаем статику которая каждые n часов обновляется) тоже вполне несложно... тем более что тяжелые ассеты (шрифты, картинки, итд) собирать вместе с приложением совсем не обязательно, их вполне можно на проде держать при грамотно настроенных заголовках кэширования.

Comment: Генерацию статики я рассматривал как вариант. Но все же интересует вопрос как другие сервисы решили этот вопрос без статики. Самое интересное, что роботы только индексную страницу не "хавают", все остальные нормально отображаются в результатах поиска (даже все локализированные)

Comment: и я думаю это не только с Vue такая беда происходит